# Tensorflow iterator Out of Range

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I have two dataset in TFRecords, one holds around 20,000 entries, other hold 1.2 million.

This code perfectly work when I use TFRecord with 20,000 entries but give out of range error when I use 1.2 million .

```
def parse(serialized):

features = \
    {
        'train/image': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
        'train/label': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64)
    }


parsed_example = tf.parse_single_example(serialized=serialized,
                                         features=features)


image_raw = parsed_example['train/image']


image = tf.decode_raw(image_raw, tf.uint8)


image = tf.cast(image, tf.float32)


label = parsed_example['train/label']


return image, label

def input_fn(filenames, train, batch_size=32, buffer_size=2048):

dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(filenames=filenames)


dataset = dataset.map(parse)

if train:

    dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=buffer_size)


    num_repeat = None
else:

    num_repeat = 1


dataset = dataset.repeat(num_repeat)


dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)


iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()


images_batch, labels_batch = iterator.get_next()


x =  {'image':images_batch}
y = labels_batch

return x, y

x,y = input_fn('train.tfrecords',False)
print(x)
with tf.Session() as sess:
   for i in range(10):
      print(sess.run(x))
```

The error is coming is this:

```
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1374, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)

OutOfRangeError: End of sequence
     [[Node: IteratorGetNext_2 = IteratorGetNext[output_shapes=[[?,?], [?]], output_types=[DT_FLOAT, DT_INT64], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](OneShotIterator_2)]]

Caused by op 'IteratorGetNext_2', defined at:
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\ipython\start_kernel.py", line 268, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\ipython\start_kernel.py", line 264, in main
    kernel.start()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelapp.py", line 478, in start
    self.io_loop.start()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\eventloop\ioloop.py", line 177, in start
    super(ZMQIOLoop, self).start()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\ioloop.py", line 888, in start
    handler_func(fd_obj, events)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\stack_context.py", line 277, in null_wrapper
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\eventloop\zmqstream.py", line 440, in _handle_events
    self._handle_recv()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\eventloop\zmqstream.py", line 472, in _handle_recv
    self._run_callback(callback, msg)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\eventloop\zmqstream.py", line 414, in _run_callback
    callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\stack_context.py", line 277, in null_wrapper
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 283, in dispatcher
    return self.dispatch_shell(stream, msg)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 233, in dispatch_shell
    handler(stream, idents, msg)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 399, in execute_request
    user_expressions, allow_stdin)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\ipkernel.py", line 208, in do_execute
    res = shell.run_cell(code, store_history=store_history, silent=silent)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\zmqshell.py", line 537, in run_cell
    return super(ZMQInteractiveShell, self).run_cell(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2728, in run_cell
    interactivity=interactivity, compiler=compiler, result=result)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2856, in run_ast_nodes
    if self.run_code(code, result):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2910, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-3-23a4ed6f3a2e>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/kakus/Desktop/landmark/tfrecord_test_outputv2.py', wdir='C:/Users/kakus/Desktop/landmark')
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 705, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)
  File "C:/Users/kakus/Desktop/landmark/tfrecord_test_outputv2.py", line 84, in <module>
    x,y = input_fn('train.tfrecords',False)
  File "C:/Users/kakus/Desktop/landmark/tfrecord_test_outputv2.py", line 76, in input_fn
    images_batch, labels_batch = iterator.get_next()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\data\ops\iterator_ops.py", line 330, in get_next
    name=name)), self._output_types,
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_dataset_ops.py", line 895, in iterator_get_next
    output_shapes=output_shapes, name=name)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py", line 787, in _apply_op_helper
    op_def=op_def)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 3271, in create_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 1650, in __init__
    self._traceback = self._graph._extract_stack()  # pylint: disable=protected-access

OutOfRangeError (see above for traceback): End of sequence
     [[Node: IteratorGetNext_2 = IteratorGetNext[output_shapes=[[?,?], [?]], output_types=[DT_FLOAT, DT_INT64], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](OneShotIterator_2)]]
```

Answer (score 0):

dataset.repeat(num_epochs) will repeat the data for the number of epochs specified. In the train mode you have specified it to be none, change it to the number of epochs you want to train the dataset.